# datetime strptime method for format HH:MM:SS.MICROSECOND

Tags: python-2.7, timestamp, strptime

I'm trying to investigate the Python time striptime method to decompose a time represented as 11:49:57.74.  The standard %H, %M, %S are able to decompose the hour , minute , second. However, since the data is a string ( which is taken in python pandas column as datatype object, the Milliseconds after the decimal second is left uninterpreted. Hence, I get an error. Could someone please advise how to parse the example so that the seconds and microseconds are correctly interpreted from the time string ? 
I would then use them to find the time delta between two time stamps.

Comment: Could you share what you have tried? And share an example to understand what you need exactly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I had correctly understood your question.

So, to convert that string time to datetime and calculate the timedelta between two times you need to do as follow:

```
timedelta = str() #declare an empty string where save the timedelta

my_string = '11:49:57.74' # first example time
another_example_time = '13:49:57.74' #second example time, invented by me for the example

first_time = datetime.strptime(my_string, "%H:%M:%S.%f") # extract the first time
second_time = datetime.strptime(another_example_time , "%H:%M:%S.%f") # extract the second time

#calculate the time delta
if(first_time > second_time):
    timedelta = first_time - second_time 
else:
    timedelta = second_time - first_time

print "The timedelta between %s and %s is: %s" % (first_time, second_time, timedelta)
```

Here obviusly you don't have any date, so the datetime library as default use **`1900-01-01`** as you can see in the result of the print:

```
The timedelta between 1900-01-01 11:49:57.740000 and 1900-01-01 13:49:57.740000 is: 2:00:00
```

I hope this solution is what you need. Next time provide a little bit more information please, or share an example with the code that you have tried to write.